# How to look up keys in dictionary when shortened key names are in another list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to look up values in a dictionary by shortened keys (The keys in the dictionary are full length), where the shortened keys are in a different list.

For example, the list might be

`names = ["Bob", "Albert", "Man", "Richard"]`,

and the dictionary I want to look up is as such:

`location_dict {"Bob Franklin":"NYC", "Albert":"Chicago", "Manfred":"San Fransisco", "Richard Walker":"Houston"}`

The code I have is:

```
for name in names:
    if name.startswith(f'{name}') in location_dict: 
       print(location_dict[name.startswith('{name}')])
```

But this doesn't work (because it's self referential, and I need a list of full key names associated with the shortened ones, I understand that much). How do I get the values of a dictionary with shortened key names? I have a list of over a 1000 names like this, and I don't know the most efficient way to do this.

**Expected output:** If I look up "Bob" from the list of names as a key for the dictionary, then it should return "NYC" from the dictionary

Comment: Add the expected output

Comment: A quick aside: If `name` is a string then `name == f'{name}'` is always `True`.

Comment: There is probably no "efficient" way of doing this other than checking every entry in the dict. Dict access is optimized around equality checking - not `startswith`

Comment: The formatted string is catch spaces after the short name e.g. if two names were 'Ken Brown' and 'Kenneth Ford', but I wanted only Ken. I've tried with regexes too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. `name.startswith(f'{name}')` will always return True.

Try this -

```
for name in names:
    for k, v in location_dict.items():
        if k.startswith(name):
            print(v)
```

To stop after the first match add a `break` statement.

```
for name in names:
    for k, v in location_dict.items():
        if k.startswith(name):
            print(v)
            break
```

Comment: So I'd have to look through every value in the dictionary no matter what?
Would it be better to use regex?

Comment: If you assume there is only one match per name you can add break after you found it. You can also sprt the names and keys and on every iteration start where the last one ended.

Comment: Oh right, thanks, that may difficult due to some shared names, I'll have to clean the data a bit for that manually. Multiple matches will occur, but it will spit out the first match and stop, no?

Comment: See my edit regarding stopping after the first match

Answer (score 1):

Try this in just one line using `any()`:

```
[v for k,v in  location_dict.items() if any(k.startswith(name) for name in names)]
```